# Button that plays sound only if headphones are plugged in

Tags: html, audio

Is it possible to make a button, in an email or on a webpage, that plays a sound file, but only if the device that clicks it has headphones plugged in?

If not headphones are plugged in, then nothing plays.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

In many cases, the device doesn't even know that headphones are plugged in.  There isn't always some indication up to software (or, even to any intelligent hardware) that headphones are attached.

This being said, if you have a predictable environment where something with headphones and something without headphones are both listed as possible output devices with separate sink IDs, you could use the [Audio Output Devices API](https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-output/) for this.  Just don't expect any accuracy at all, if you don't already know about exact hardware being used by  your users.

Comment: I was pretty sure, that this is actually supported through js https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices

Comment: @Stender The device itself often isn't aware whether or not headphones are plugged in.  Any software reporting of headphone state is largely a guess, when it's available at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [AudioChannels API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/API/AudioChannelManager/headphones). It is supported on the Firefox Browser and Firefox OS.

The headphones read-only property of the AudioChannelManager interface returns a Boolean that indicates whether headphones are plugged into the device. A true value means that headphone are plugged in; false means they aren't.

Example:

```
if (navigator.mozAudioChannelManager) {
  navigator.mozAudioChannelManager.onheadphoneschange = function() {
    if(navigator.mozAudioChannelManager.headphones == true) {
      var notification = new Notification('Headphones plugged in!');
    } else {
      var notification = new Notification('Headphones unplugged!');
    }
  }
}
```